# Show that $|a+b|=|a|+|b|\Leftrightarrow ab\geq0$

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

Assume $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that
$$|a+b|=|a|+|b|\Leftrightarrow ab\geq0$$

The triangle inequality says that for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$.

So I believe I can say
$$|a+b|-|a|-|b|\leq 0$$

I am not quite sure where to go from there, though, or if I am on the right track.

Comment: What's a more wordy way of saying $ab \geq 0$ ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By squaring the two sides,

$$ |a+b|=|a|+|b|\Leftrightarrow a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = a^2 + 2|ab| + b^2.$$

Thus 
$$ |a+b|=|a|+|b|\Leftrightarrow ab = |ab| \Leftrightarrow ab\geq 0.$$

Comment: I love when these things don't become case-seeking. +1